# How to use a local APPlication database

Tags: c#, database

I have an application in which such a large amount of data is loaded at the beginning that the waiting time for the users is no longer justifiable.
At first only data is loaded to fill a listbox explorer, which serves as browser to load the remaining information when selecting the item. So much for the data model.

I now intend to maintain a local data source and only update the data that the user selects, but I have to deal with the question if I should keep the finished objects for the model or the raw data.

Has anyone played around with the different approaches and can say/link to what is best approach in terms of maintenance and performance? I work with .NET

Comment: You might be interested in lazy loading, and asynchronously loading the data.

Comment: You might want to perform heavy/slow operations on another thread. See `Task.Run()`.

Comment: I will test the lazy loading approach, maybe this does the trick. Threading seems not to be a solution because the bottle neck is the network itselve. I call a stored procedures that return a Index list with a huge amount of data. Maybe chunking the index list is another option.

Comment: I mentioned threading in order to avoid doing CPU-intensive work on the UI thread. This is to avoid having the UI freeze.